# Show that a sequence does not converge

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I have a very similar question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812313/convergence-under-a-hilbert-space) and so I'll change my letters to match:

Let $\{\varphi_n\}^∞_{n=1}$ be an orthonormal sequence (not necessarily a basis) in a Hilbert space. Let $\{λ_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of numbers. Define $T:H \to H$ by $Tx=∑_{n=1}^\infty λ_n⟨x,\varphi_n⟩\varphi_n$. Show that if $\sup_n|λ_n|=\infty$ then ther is $x \in H$ for which $∑_{n=1}^\infty λ_n⟨x,\varphi_n⟩\varphi_n$ does not converge.

**Note the difference with $\sup_n|λ_n|=\infty$**.

If I Show that there is a subsequence $\lambda_{n_k}$ for which $|λ_{n_k}|\geq k$ can I then somehow use this to construct $x$ using only $\varphi_{n_k}$ and show that $x$ does not converges?

Comment: You can surely say the subsequence exists: define $n_0=0$ and, for $k>0$, $n_k$ as the least integer $m$ greater than $n_{k-1}$ with $|\lambda_m|\ge k$; since the sequence $|\lambda_n|$ is unbounded, such $m$ exists.

Comment: Sorry. I reedited to emphasize the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sup_n|\lambda_n|=\infty$, there exists a subsequence $\{\lambda_{n_k}\}$ such that $|\lambda_{n_k}|>k$. Then $$T\varphi_{n_k}=\lambda_{n_k}\varphi_{n_k},$$ so that $\lambda I-T$ is not injective and $\lambda_{n_k}\in\sigma(T)$, where $$\sigma(T) = \{z\in\mathbb C: \lambda I-T\text{ is not invertible} \} $$ is the spectrum of $T$. This implies that the spectral radius of $T$, $$\rho(T) :=\sup\{|\lambda|:\lambda\in\sigma(T)\} $$ is infinite. By Gelfand's formula for the spectral radius of bounded operators $$\rho(A) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\|A^k\|^{\frac1k} $$ and the inequality $\|A^k\|^{\frac1k}\leqslant \|A\|$, we see that $T$ is unbounded, or equivalently that $T$ is not continuous. It follows that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $H$ such that $x_n\to x\in H$ and $Tx_n\not\to Tx$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Sorry but I lost you there. What did you mean by "so that $\lambda I - T$ is not injective and $\lambda _{n_k} \in \sigma (T)$"? What did you mean by the notations $\sigma$ and $I$ in this context?

Comment: If $Tx=\lambda x$ and $x\ne 0$, then $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$. In other words, $(\lambda I-T)x=0$ where $I$ is the identity operator, so that $\lambda I-T$ is not invertible and hence $\lambda$ is in the spectrum of $T$.